# How to use rounded value for join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, rounding

i'm just learning SQL today and i never thought how fun it's until i'm fiddling with it.
I got a problem and i need a help.

i have 2 tables, Customer and Rate, with details stated below

**Customer**

```
idcustomer = int  
namecustomer = varchar  
rate = decimal(3,0)  

with value as described:  
idcustomer---namecustomer---rate  
1---JOHN DOE---100  
2---MARY JANE---90   
3---CLIVE BAKER---12  
4---DANIEL REYES---47
```

**Rate**

```
rate = decimal(3,0)  
description = varchar(40)  

with value as described:  
rate---description  
10---G Rank  
20---F Rank  
30---E Rank  
40---D Rank  
50---C Rank  
60---B Rank  
70---A Rank  
80---S Rank  
90---SS Rank  
100---SSS Rank
```

Then i ran query below in order to round all values in customer.rate field then inner join it with rate table.

```
SELECT *, round(rate,-1) as roundedrate
FROM customer INNER JOIN rate ON customer.roundedrate = rate.rate
```

It didn't produce this result:

```
idcustomer---namecustomer---rate---roundedrate---description  
1---JOHN DOE---100---100---SSS Rank  
2---MARY JANE---90---90---SS Rank  
3---CLIVE BAKER---12---10---G Rank  
4---DANIEL REYES---47---50---C Rank
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I'm removing the extraneous database tags, but you should add the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should produce an 'ambigious column' error because you're not specifying a table name when referring to `rate` (in `round(rate,-1)`), which exists in both tables.

Also, the `where` part of a sql query is executed before the `select` part, so you can't refer to the alias `customer.roundedrate` in your `where` statement.

Try this instead

```
SELECT *, round(customer.rate,-1) as roundedrate
FROM customer INNER JOIN rate ON round(customer.rate,-1) = rate.rate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94a60/2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery for this:

```
select c.*,
       (select r.description
        from rate r
        where r.rate <= c.rate
        order by r.rate desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as description
from customer c;
```

Note:  `fetch first 1 row only` is ANSI standard SQL, which some databases do not support.  MySQL uses `limit`.  Older versions of SQL Server use `select top 1` instead.

Comment: Sorry, i have tried the query even if i haven't study about subquery. it doesn't work for me, i'm using latest mySQL v5.7.12 for windows. Did i have to change something?

Comment: Change `fetch fiirst 1 row only` to `limit 1`.